# html5 manipulating the elements in canvas

Tags: html

I want to know how to load an image into the HTML5 canvas. Specifically, I want a script that swaps one image for another on the canvas during mouse over with the original image fading out. I am new to HTML5 and have this code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawbackground() {
        char.fillStyle="blue";
        cxt.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
    }

        var charx=0;
        var chary=0;
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
        var char=c.getContext("2d");
        drawbackground();
        char.fillStyle="black";
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src='map1.png';
        imgObj.onload = function () {           
        // Draw the image on the canvas
        char.drawImage(imgObj, 10, 10);
        }       

</script>
```

Is this in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the HTML5 Canvas. To swap an image on mouse over it is easiest to use a JavaScript Framework called jQuery, get it for free here: http://jquery.com/.

With jQuery all you need to do is something like the following:

First, create an image Tag.

```
<img src="image1.png" id="myimage" />
```

Next add JavaScript to handle the mouse over event. You can learn more about jQuery events here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

```
$("#myimage").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).src = this.src.replace("image2.png");
});
```

The example above will change the image on mouse over. To do the fade effects, you need to do a little more: You can learn more about jQuery effects here: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

I would create two images for the effect and position each over the other with the css property set to hide image 2.

```
<div id="imageHolder">
<img src="image1.png" id="myimage1" />
<img src="image2.png" id="myimage2" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

Next comes the JavaScript:

```
$("#imageHolder").mouseover(function() {
  $("#image1").fadeOut();
  $("#image2").show();
});

   $("#imageHolder").mouseout(function() {
      $("#image1").fadeIn();
      $("#image2").hide();
    });
```

There are many ways to accomplish this and the code above is not tested, but should provide you with a basis to quickly create the desired effect.